# If-else statement not working correctly in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, private

I've had this problem for several hours now and I cannot for the life of me figure out what's wrong... I am no code pro so I'm probably missing something really simple. What I want to do is transfer data from my controller method to my model. Please tell me how to solve this in the best way.

The controller:

```
class Some_controller extends CI_Controller {

    function controller_method() {
        $this->load->model('Some_model');

        $boolean = /* get tiny int */;
        $data['result'] = $this->Some_model->do_stuff();
        $this->load->view('Some_view', $data);
    }
}
```

The model:

```
   class Some_model extends CI_Model {

        private $var;

        function __construct() {
            $boolean ? $this->var= 100 : $this->var = 1000;
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function do_stuff() {
            $data = $this->var;
            /* manipulate $data */
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

The view:

```
...
<p><?php echo $result; ?></p>
...
```

Comment: What is your actual error message? Maybe the return `$data` is simply empty?

Comment: I don't get an error message really, it just doesn't give me the expected answer. If I send $boolean to the view and do the same expression I get the correct answer, which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you pass data from a controller to a model:

```
//controller 
function controller_method()
{
   $this->load->model('some_model');
   $boolean = TRUE;
   $this->some_model->do_suff($boolean);
}

//model
function do_stuff($boolean)
{
  //check $boolean value
  if($boolean){
     $this->var = 100;
   }else{
     $this->var = 1000;
   }  
}
```

I recommend you spend some time reading the CI  user guide:

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to update $var for some strange reason.